# is there a solution for this flutter problem?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

How can I fix : android license status unknown
when I write(flutter doctor --android-licenses) there are a error
note: the project run on desktop and web but on android there are a java problem

every thing in youtube video :)

Comment: Show us the full output